# How to modify original query caused by model for referencing foreign table

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am now coding a simple pizza ordering app with laravel.
Here are my current coding:

```html
class Order extends Model {
    protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['pizzaid', 'date'];
}

class Order extends JsonResource {
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'pizzaid' => $this->pizzaid,
            'date' => $this->date,
            'pizzadata' => PizzaResource::collection(Pizza::where('id', $this->pizzaid)->get()),
        ];
    }
}

class Pizza extends Model {
    protected $table = 'pizzas';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'detail'];
}

class Pizza extends JsonResource {
    public  function    toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'picture' => $this->picture,
            'detail' => $this->detail,
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see here, every order resource must show pizza resource referenced by pizzaid. But for every order resource, my code executes 2 sqls of order and pizza. I want to executed only 1 sql. How can I fix my code?
DB Table 'orders' has already foreign key with 'pizzas'.

Comment: I can not see where your code executes 2 queries.